# How do I execute a proper IF-THEN statement?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

When I run this module I get an Object Required error.  I'm a novice with VBA and I don't see what's wrong with the code.

```
Sub CountOccurances()
Dim Total As Integer
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Row As Integer

Total = 0
For Column = 2 To 51
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").[13,Column].Value = 1 Then
        For Row = 12 To 16
          If Worksheets("Sheet1").[Row, Column].Value = 2 Then Worksheets("Sheet1").[20,Row+8].Value = Total + 1
        Next Row
    End If
Next Column
End Sub
```

I have tried a few modifications, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cells property, as in:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(13, Column).Value = 1
```

instead of the shortcut notation; the latter is good for a range defined by a starting and ending cell reference separated by a colon (like [A1:C5])